# How to round to nearest integer given a tolerance

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

Assume I have tolerance of 0.01 (meaning anything below this value should be rounded)

I have a number 1.009 which should be rounded to 1.0 because its smaller than the tolerance but the number 1.01 should remain, likewise 0.99 should remain but 0.91 should round up to 1.00

I want this logic to apply for all integers, if that's not possible then array of numbers.

Here is my attempt at doing it just for the integer 1.00

https://jsbin.com/yuyozopeno/1/edit?js,console,output

```
function tolerate(num, acceptableTolerance) {
    var difference = Math.abs(1.00 - num);
    if (difference <= acceptableTolerance) {
        num = 1.00;
    }

    return num;
}

console.log(tolerate(1.01, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(1.001, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(0.99, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(0.9991, 0.01))
```

Also is there a better name for this type of mathmatical operation?

Comment: I'm a tad confused at what you're asking. 0.91 => 1.00; 0.99 => 0.99; 1.009 => 1.009? I can't quite understand the pattern you're after.

Comment: To specify the tolerance of rounding. That is, how "close" a number must be to an integer in order for rounding to occur. Just explaining that made me realize what I need to do, simply execute `Math.round`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you. You were just missing the general case of finding the nearest integer, and luckily javascript has a nice function to do it for you, `Math.round`

```js
function tolerate(num, acceptableTolerance) {
    var nearestRoundNumber = Math.round(num);
    var difference = Math.abs(nearestRoundNumber - num);
    if (difference <= acceptableTolerance) {
        num = nearestRoundNumber;
    }

    return num;
}

console.log(tolerate(1.01, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(1.001, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(0.99, 0.01))
console.log(tolerate(0.9991, 0.01))
```

Comment: You need to be careful with boundary cases. For example, `tolerate(2.01, 0.01)` will give `2`, which probably isn't what the OP wants.